# Cibonfire Fix Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to use cibonfire breadcumb

`<?php echo breadcrumb(); ?>`

but, the link direct me to up directory, i've got `Object not found!` error.

How do i fix this link location?

`http://localhost:8082/admin/content`

which is should be

`http://localhost:8082/ces/admin/content`

Thanks,

Comment: What is the meaning of each of those two links? Like is one what you want and the other what it is outputting? Please specify, your question is too vague without that information.

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://cibonfire.com/docs/files2/designers/utilities-txt.html#breadcrumb). Per the docs:

> The breadcrumb is built from the URI segments of the current page.  If
>   the default uri segments will not work for a page in your application,
>   you can pass an array of key/value pairs that represent the crumbs. 
>   The key of each pair is the value that will be shown, while the value
>   of each pair represents the url segment to pass into it.

Comment: i hope it could be done without assigning array on each page in my project :(

Comment: Your file hierarchy is what is likely causing it. I presume you are not using the default hierarchy reason the links are off. Passing the array is meant for such situations.